# Настроить форму php

Tags: php, php7

Написал небольшой код, чтоб сообщения приходили на почту к заказчику, но по какой-то причине код не отрабатывает. Всё внизу.

```
 <form class="button" id="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
            <div class="user"></div>
            <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" name="contactname" id="contactname">
            <div class="telephone"></div>
            <input class="name number" type="text" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="number" id="numbers">
            <button name="submit" type="submit"><p>ПОЛУЧИТЬ РАСЧЁТ</p></button>
        </form>
        <?php
      if (isset($_POST['contactname'])) {$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];}
      if (isset($_POST['number'])) {$number = $_POST['number'];}
      //Если форма отправлена
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      //Проверка Поля ИМЯ
        $emailTo = 'ooo_ssd86@mail.ru'; //email
        $body = "Name: $contactname \n\n Number:\n $number";
        $headers = 'From: My Site';
        mail($emailTo, $body, $headers);
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: скорее всего в папку спам идут письма

Comment: там тоже их нет.

Comment: На какой системе пробуете? Если вдруг windows, то в ней нет встроенного почтовика, адрес надо в php.ini прописывать

Comment: закинул на хостинг и там делаю

Comment: Для начала, что возвращает **функция** `mail`?

Comment: Обычно From должен адрес отправителя (этого же сервера) содержать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте папку спама.
Попробовал у себя, код рабочий и попал мне в директорию спама.

Comment: Может он запускает это без сервера ?

Comment: У меня был бесплатный хостинг, через 20 минут обычный куплю

Comment: @VashkaStream , на бесплатных хостингах может быть отключена функция `php mail` .

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. Поможет избежать множества проблем (особенно при масштабировании приложения).